# Multivariable calculus: determining $dV$ when $0 \leq ax+by+cz \leq l$, $0 \leq dx+ey+fz \leq m$ and $0 \leq gx+hy+iz \leq n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

As my previous question had severe typos, I deleted my question and re-asking.

Suppose that we are solving a multivariable calculus problem. The region that we are integrating over is described by $0 \leq ax+by+cz \leq l$, $0 \leq dx+ey+fz \leq m$ and $0 \leq gx+hy+iz \leq n$ where $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,l,m,n$ are pre-determined constant number and $x,y,z$ are variables, as usual.

We set $A=ax+by+cz$, $B=dx+ey+fz$, $C=gx+hy+iz$.

Let us say we want to find out $\iiint_E f(x,y,z)dV$. In this case, what would be a possible form for $dV?$ Would there be any convenient coordinate system?

For example, let us say that $f(x,y,z) = ABC$. What would happen?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your limits do bound a region in space, yes. In this case it is convenient to create new variables

$$
\begin{cases}
\overline{X} = ax+by+cz, \\
\overline{Y} = dx+ey+fz, \\
\overline{Z} = gx+hj+iz,
\end{cases}
$$

with limits $0 \leq \overline{X} \leq l, 0 \leq \overline{Y} \leq m, 0 \leq \overline{Z} \leq n$. You have to isolate the old variables $x,y,z$ in terms of the new $\overline{X}, \overline{Y}, \overline{Z}$ ones. In this particular case this is easy because they are all linear. Hence, you have

$$
\begin{bmatrix} x & y & z \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix} \overline{X} \\ \overline{Y} \\ \overline{Z} \end{bmatrix}.
$$

The function you are integrating takes a new face $f(x,y,z) = h(\overline{X}, \overline{Y}, \overline{Z})$ and all that is left is the Jacobian. By calculating

$$\begin{vmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \overline{X}} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \overline{Y}} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \overline{Z}} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial \overline{X}} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \overline{Y}} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \overline{Z}} \\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial \overline{X}} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial \overline{Y}} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial \overline{Z}} \end{vmatrix}$$

you will get

$$dx \, dy \, dz = \left\vert \frac{\partial (x,y,z)}{\partial (\overline{X}, \overline{Y}, \overline{Z})} \right\vert \, d \overline{X} \, d \overline{Y} \, d \overline{Z},$$

turning the triple integral into

$$\iiint\limits_{V} f(x,y,z) \, dx \, dy \, dz = \int_0^l \int_0^m \int_0^n h \left( \overline{X}, \overline{Y}, \overline{Z} \right) \left\vert \frac{\partial (x,y,z)}{\partial (\overline{X}, \overline{Y}, \overline{Z})} \right\vert \, d \overline{X} \, d \overline{Y} \, d \overline{Z}.$$

Notice how this is just integrating over a parallelepiped, which should be easier.